# Is it possible to update a table using an attached excel and/or text file in table field?

Tags: ms-access, attachment

To be more specific.  I have a table that contains an attached file (added by a user within a form) I need to use the data in that file to update a table to be used in other queries. *fingers crossed

Comment: Not before first exporting it.

Comment: exporting the attachment ... to the hard drive?  I am creating a database that i need to hand off for someone (around the world) to use.  I am trying to avoid having them update links or paths to files.

Comment: You can just use the temp folder and clean up after you're done. See [this tutorial](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WorkingWithTempFilesAndFolders.htm) by Chip Pearson.

Comment: Or the 'attachment' can sit in folder next to the db and code can use `CurrentProject.Path & "\myFilename"`.